# How can i summerize posts or news automatically in word press site?

Tags: plugins, posts, customization

Is there any module or sample code for summerize post by intelligence algorithms?

I want to summerize 1000 last posts automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Summy: Excerpt Extraction](http://wordpress.org/plugins/summy/) WordPress plugin has well documented code to use the [Sum+my algorithms](http://summy.komposta.net/).

Instead of looking for a solution that is already used in WordPress, you might find more solutions by searching for PHP solutions that summarize articles and then integrating them into WordPress. WordPress [provides a filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) that can be used to edit the content for a summary.